# How to update a MYSQL column if the value's exist in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a two tables in my database, tableA and tableB.

```
tableA:

id | col1  | col2  | in_b
-----------------------
1  | "abc" | "efg" | false
2  | "foo" | "bar" | false
```

```
tableB: 

id | col1  | col2  
------------------
1  | "abc" | "bar"
```

I want to update the in_b column so that it is true if either col1 or col2's values matches a row in tableB. For example, both `in_b` flags would be true, because "abc" is in col1 of tableB and "bar" is in col2 of tableB. col1 and col2 are not unique.

What is the best way to update the in_b flag?

Comment: Is it just two columns in real life as well?

Comment: Are you wanting to check match of *every* row in `tableA` against *every* row in `tableB`? And what specifically are you meaning with *`col1` and `col2` are not unique*?

Comment: Yes, I want to match every row of tableA against every row of tableB.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want something along the lines of

```
UPDATE tableA
SET in_b = TRUE
    WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM tableB
                   WHERE (tableB.col1 = tableA.col1 OR tableB.col2 = tableA.col2)
                 )
```

Comment: Please note in OP's description of his sample case: "*both `in_b` flags would be true*"

Comment: Ah yes, the `id` field is not the FK. Missed that the first time. Answer adjusted accordingly.

Comment: You'll have to explain it to me then, o great one. I've seen Jorge's response, but don't agree that the OP asked that A.col1 and B.col2 need to be be compared.

Comment: That's exactly what the OP answered on the comments. And on his question He stated `col1 or col2's values matches a row in tableB` I understand `a row` as all columns. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @Jorge Campos: I don't read it that way - the OP's example shows he is comparing col1 to col1, and col2 to col2. I'm still none the wiser what PM 77-1 thinks the issue is...

Comment: I think he is thinking as same as I am therefore you would be incorrect. But that is the OP to decide right ;) (since he didn't provide enough examples). And for the examples I agree with you that is col1 with col1 and col2 with col2. But I posted my query to the case it is not.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your question there is no link between the IDs on both table and try to match both columns from `tablea` with `tableb` (col1, col2), just a full search for the values. So your update would be:

```
update tablea a inner join tableb b on ( (a.col1=b.col1 or a.col1=b.col2) or 
                                       (a.col2=b.col1 or a.col2=b.col2) )
   set a.in_b = true;
```

See it here on fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b847/1

In my example I've added a row to the `tablea` which doesn't have any matches on `tableb`