# MySQL check large amount of data

Tags: php, mysql, hash

I have two tables named `actual` and `check`

Table `actual` contains 50 million rows and each row contains 32-bit hashes

Table `check` contains 10 million rows and each row contains 32-bit hashes

I have to verify if the hashes from `check` table are in `actual` table or not.

I tried MySQL Join query like

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `check` 
  LEFT 
  JOIN `actual` 
    on `check`.hash = `actual`.hash;
```

Even on 16GB RAM machine MySQL is crashing.

I tried using PHP script by adding additional fields to Table `check` as field names hash, status, found.

Status & found are default 0 and PHP will check each record and update status to 1 and found to 1 if found.

Is there any way to check millions or records faster?

The other way I have INSERT using IGNORE for unique hashes and checking how many were not appended but its complex process.

**The PHP code I am using is but its very slow**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `check` where status = 0 LIMIT 0, 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $check = "SELECT * FROM `actual` where hash = '".$row["hash"]."'";
    $checkx = $conn->query($check);

    $checky = "UPDATE `check` SET `status` = 1, `found` = 0 WHERE hash = '".$row["hash"]."'";
    $conn->query($checky);
    if ($checkx->num_rows > 0) {
      $checky = "UPDATE `check` SET `status` = 1, `found` = 1 WHERE hash = '".$row["hash"]."'";
      $conn->query($checky);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Does the column have index?

Comment: @Raptor - yes it does.

Comment: Can we see SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for both tables, and the EXPLAIN for your query?

Comment: If you are executing the select in php to use the retrieved data to update the records later, then do not bother, just directly use an update statement.

Comment: @Shadow did you mean don't use two different statements for select and then update? Instead, you suggest using one statement?

Comment: Yep, similarly to the answer you got below. See the answers to this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27789956/how-to-update-a-mysql-column-if-the-values-exist-in-another-table

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood you right, a sub-query is all you need:

```
UPDATE check SET status=1, found=1 WHERE hash IN (SELECT hash FROM actual)
```

I don't have enough data to do a meaningful performance comparison - try it and see.

**Edit:**
With a clearer idea of the requirement gleaned by looking at the PHP solution, here's an updated query:

```
UPDATE `check` SET status=1, found=(hash IN (SELECT hash FROM actual))  WHERE status=0
```

Note:

- It's important that `actual.hash` is indexed, or searching the `actual` table will take an age.
- Depending on the balance between checked and unchecked rows in `check`, it might be worth indexing `check.status` too. If most rows are unchecked there will be no benefit, but it could work well if there are only a few unchecked ones. Writing to an indexed table could be significantly slower. You'd need to experiment with your data set to find out.

Comment: I updated my question, can you please let me know how to do something like

`UPDATE check SET status=1, found=1 WHERE hash IN (SELECT hash FROM actual) AND status=0` Update found=1 only when there is a match found else status=1 will still be updated so that I don't check duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Use a multi-table UPDATE instead of `IN ( SELECT ... )`

Also

- What version of MySQL?
- Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  We need to see the engine, indexes, datatypes, etc.
- `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool_size';`

What do you mean by "crashing"?  Reboot?  mysqld died?  Or simply that the query took forever?

Once we have optimized the query, if it still is too slow, I will show you how to do it in stages.  And that will probably involve directly writing SQL, not by going through Django.